# How to output last column element of NumPy 2D array ignoring nan in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nan

I have a NumPy 2D array as shown below:

**data.dat**

```
X1  X2  X3  X4
1   1   1   1
2   2   4   2
3   3   9   3
4   4   16  4
5   5   25  5
6   6   36  6
7   nan 49  7
8   nan 64  8
9   nan 81  nan
10  nan nan nan
```

Now how do I output the last element of each column ignoring nan in the array. I tried without success the code:

```
A[~np.isnan(A)][-1]
```

**Code used**

```
import numpy as np
with open('data.dat', "r") as data:
    while True:
        line = data.readline()
        if not line.startswith('#'):
            break
    data_header = [i for i in line.strip().split('\t') if i]
A = np.genfromtxt('data.dat', names = data_header, dtype = float, delimiter = '\t')
```

Comment: Please post the actual array or something that users can at least copy paste.

Comment: What are you doing in the while loop? Wouldn't `arr = np.genfromtxt("data.dat",names=True,delimiter = '\t')` do the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

If A were a plain NumPy array of dtype 'float' (instead of a structured array)
then you could use

```
import numpy as np
nan = np.nan
A = np.array([[  1.,   1.,   1.,   1.],
              [  2.,   2.,   4.,   2.],
              [  3.,   3.,   9.,   3.],
              [  4.,   4.,  16.,   4.],
              [  5.,   5.,  25.,   5.],
              [  6.,   6.,  36.,   6.],
              [  7.,  nan,  49.,   7.],
              [  8.,  nan,  64.,   8.],
              [  9.,  nan,  81.,  nan],
              [ 10.,  nan,  nan,  nan]])

print(A[(~np.isnan(A)).cumsum(axis=0).argmax(axis=0), np.arange(A.shape[1])])
```

which yields

```
array([ 10.,   6.,  81.,   8.])
```

Given the structured array, such as the one generated by

```
import numpy as np

with open('data.dat', "r") as data:
    # per Padraic Cunningham's suggestion
    A = np.genfromtxt("data.dat", names=True, delimiter = '\t')
```

I think the easiest way to obtain the desired result is to *view* the structured array as a plain NumPy array of dtype 'float':

```
B = A.view('float').reshape(A.shape[0], -1)
```

and then proceed as before:

```
print(B[(~np.isnan(B)).cumsum(axis=0).argmax(axis=0), np.arange(B.shape[1])])
```

---

**How it works:**

Given a plain NumPy array of dtype 'float', such as

```
In [357]: B
Out[357]: 
array([[ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [  1.,   1.,   1.,   1.],
       [  2.,   2.,   4.,   2.],
       [  3.,   3.,   9.,   3.],
       [  4.,   4.,  16.,   4.],
       [  5.,   5.,  25.,   5.],
       [  6.,   6.,  36.,   6.],
       [  7.,  nan,  49.,   7.],
       [  8.,  nan,  64.,   8.],
       [  9.,  nan,  81.,  nan],
       [ 10.,  nan,  nan,  nan]])
```

we can use `np.isnan` to find where the non-nan values are:

```
In [358]: ~np.isnan(B)
Out[358]: 
array([[False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Now we can use `cumsum` to compute a cumulative sum for each column (False is treated as 0, True as 1):

```
In [359]: (~np.isnan(B)).cumsum(axis=0)
Out[359]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 2,  2,  2,  2],
       [ 3,  3,  3,  3],
       [ 4,  4,  4,  4],
       [ 5,  5,  5,  5],
       [ 6,  6,  6,  6],
       [ 7,  6,  7,  7],
       [ 8,  6,  8,  8],
       [ 9,  6,  9,  8],
       [10,  6,  9,  8]])
```

Notice that the maximum value in each column is due to the value achieved by the
last True in each column.

Therefore, we can find the index corresponding the the first occurrance of the maximum value in each column by using `np.argmax`:

```
In [360]: (~np.isnan(B)).cumsum(axis=0).argmax(axis=0)
Out[360]: array([10,  6,  9,  8])
```

This gives the row index number for each column.
To find the corresponding value in the array we could then use:

```
In [361]: B[(~np.isnan(B)).cumsum(axis=0).argmax(axis=0), np.arange(B.shape[1])]
Out[361]: array([ 10.,   6.,  81.,   8.])
```

Comment: Would it be better using pandas? `df = pd.read_csv("data.dat", header=0, comment="#",delimiter="\t")`,  then use .values?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Yes, for large CSV, `pd.read_csv` is faster than `np.genfromtxt`. See http://wesmckinney.com/blog/a-new-high-performance-memory-efficient-file-parser-engine-for-pandas/ for some discussion and benchmarks. The benchmarks there do not use `np.genfromtxt`, but I did make a big CSV for this problem using `df = pd.concat([pd.read_table('data', sep='\s+')]*10000, ignore_index=True)` and found `pd.read_csv` to be faster about 5x faster than `np.genfromtxt`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
import numpy as np

ss = """1   1   1   1
        2   2   4   2
        3   3   9   3
        4   4   16  4
        5   5   25  5
        6   6   36  6
        7   nan 49  7
        8   nan 64  8
        9   nan 81  nan
        10  nan nan nan"""

# build Matrix from string:
AA = np.array([[float(c) for c in rw.split()]
               for rw in ss.splitlines()])

# extract last finte column element:
cl_finite = np.array([cl[np.isfinite(cl)][-1] for cl in AA.T])
print(cl_finite)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine, at least if all columns have a non-nan element.

```
In [36]: [l[~np.isnan(l)][-1] for l in A.transpose()]
Out[36]: [10.0, 6.0, 81.0, 8.0]
```